# Ruby on Rails and PHP on Same Apache Web Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, ruby-on-rails

So I am really used to LAMP stacks and have an Apache and PHP setup on my Ubuntu server with about 30 PHP sites. I want to throw a new project up on the site that is built on Ruby on Rails. Is it possible to continue to use Apache and have the RoR project sit right next to all of the other projects in /var/www/?

Also, what's the best way to get RoR installed on a default Ubuntu server install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can with pretty much any Rails app server. In all cases, the Rails app runs in a separate process and the frontend web server (Apache in this case) passes requests through to it. For standalone servers like mongrel and unicorn you run the app server manually and use mod_proxy_http to pass requests through. Passenger lets Apache manage the rails process automatically and use a lightweight internal communication protocol rather than http.

If you're just getting started I'd advise using Passenger; my experience is that other servers are easier for larger clustered deployments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). It's Apache module and allows you to run rails applications.

For RoR installation have a look at [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)